# alternative to case_when that does calculations

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking for another option in dplyr for doing calculations, based on the value of other variables.

In this specific case, I've sorted my dataframe by the individual ID and time (ts) of each observation.  For each individual, I want to calculate the difference in time between the first and second, then second and third, etc., observation, and if the observations occur on different days, I want to subtract the amount of time at night (nightLength) - essentially getting at maximum *day* time between observations.

However, I need an option for a dplyr alternative to case_when that can do these calculations.

E.g.,

```
df %>% arrange(ID, ts)
  mutate(nightLength = 24 - difftime(sunset, sunrise, unit="hours"),
         gap = case_when(ID == lag(ID) & day == lag(day) ~
                           difftime(ts, lag(ts), units="hours"), 
                         ID == lag(ID) & day != lag(day) ~
                           difftime(ts, lag(ts), units="hours") - nightLength,
                         TRUE ~ NA_real_))
```

Comment: Is ```mutate``` an option? Combined with ```if_else``` if you need it? What's the issue with ```case_when```?

Comment: Thanks @JesseTweedle.  It appears all I needed was () around difftime(ts, lag(ts), units="hours") - nightLength, otherwise I kept getting this error: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: must be type double, not character.